# Javascript show alerts when time is not possible

Tags: javascript

We are a taxi company with the following opening times:
Monday till Friday from 07:00 till 17:00. We have a booking program where customers can book their taxi online but we have some little problems because if a customer books a drive for the next morning at 07:00 on the evening before we cannot process the booking because we open at 07:00.

So I am trying to create these functions:

- In the weekend (Saturday and Sunday) the first booking is allowed at Monday morning at 09:00.
- When booking for the next day after 17:00 till 07:00 you can only book the drive after 08:59.

When a customer books a drive for next week on 07:00 it must be possible. It only should not be possible on the two examples above.

Here is the code I am struggling with:

```
function tijdcheck() {
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + "" + today.getMinutes();
    alert(time);
    if(today.getDay() == 6 || today.getDay() == 2) {
        var picked_date = document.getElementById("Gewenste_datum").value;
        var picked_date_stripped = new Date(picked_date);
        const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
        const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((picked_date_stripped - today) / oneDay));
        var time = document.getElementById("Gewenste_tijd").value;
        var time_stripped = time.replace(':','');
        if (diffDays < 2) {
            if (time_stripped > 0659 && time_stripped < 0859){
                alert('kan niet');
            }
        }
    } else if (time > 1700 && time < 0900){
        var picked_date = document.getElementById("Gewenste_datum").value;
        var picked_date_stripped = new Date(picked_date);
        const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
        const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((picked_date_stripped - today) / oneDay));
        if (diffDays < 0) {
            alert ('kan niet');
        }
    }
}
```

The function is called when the `Gewenste_tijd` field is changing.

Does someone know how I can make the functions work?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Your code explicitly assembles the time value as a string, but the comparisons are all with numbers. You'll also have to make sure time values (hours and minutes) are padded with leading zeros when necessary.

Comment: Could you send a working Demo? Also you should never do your verification on the Front End.

Answer (score 0):

There are five cases to consider:

- closed today: next + next[open]+buffer
- not open yet: today + today[open]+buffer
- closed already: next + next[open]+buffer
- ok for today: today + time+buffer
- not enough time for today: next + next[open]

`function nextBooking(now, openDaysHours, buffer)` takes the following arguments:

- `now`: a `Date()` Object
- `openDaysHours`: an week Array of day Arrays: closed = empty day Array (`[]`), open = HH:mm Strings - one for opening time and one for closing time (example: `["07:00", "17:00"]`)
- `buffer`: how much time does it take to arrange a ride, HH:mm String

```js
function nextBooking(now, openDaysHours, buffer) {
  if(arguments.length<3) {
    console.log("check your arguments");
    return;
  }
  console.log("now is "+now);  // used for testing
  function hms2m(hmString) {
    var [h, m]=hmString.split(":");
    return 60*h+(+m);
  };
  function m2hms(minutes) {
    return ("0"+Math.floor(minutes/60)).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+(minutes)%60).slice(-2);
  }
  function nextOpenDay(today) {
    today=(today+1)%7;
    var noInfiniteLoop=1;
    while(openDaysHours[today][0]==Infinity && noInfiniteLoop<7) {
      today=(today+1)%7;
      noInfiniteLoop++;
    }
    if(noInfiniteLoop==7) return false;
    return today;
  }
  openDaysHours=openDaysHours.map(hours=>hours.length?[hms2m(hours[0]), hms2m(hours[1])]:[Infinity, -Infinity]);
  buffer=hms2m(buffer);
  var nowdow=now.getDay();
  var nowtime=60*now.getHours()+now.getMinutes();
  var dow, time;

  if(openDaysHours[nowdow][0]==Infinity) {
    // next + next[open]+buffer
    dow=nextOpenDay(nowdow);
    if(dow!==false) time=openDaysHours[dow][0]+buffer;
  }
  else if(nowtime<openDaysHours[nowdow][0]) {
    // today + today[open]+buffer
    dow=nowdow;
    time=openDaysHours[dow][0]+buffer;
  }
  else if(nowtime>openDaysHours[nowdow][1]) {
    // next + next[open]+buffer
    dow=nextOpenDay(nowdow);
    time=openDaysHours[dow][0]+buffer;
  }
  else if(nowtime+buffer<openDaysHours[nowdow][1]) {
    // today + time+buffer
    dow=nowdow;
    time=nowtime+buffer;
  }
  else {
    // next + next[open]
    dow=nextOpenDay(nowdow);
    time=openDaysHours[dow][0];
  }
  if(dow===false) console.log("Sorry, we're permanently closed");
  else console.log(
    "You can order a taxi for "+
    (nowdow==dow?"today":["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][dow])+
    " after "+
    m2hms(time)
  );
}

var daysAndHoursOpen=[[], ["07:00", "17:00"], ["07:00", "17:00"], ["07:00", "17:00"], ["07:00", "17:00"], ["07:00", "17:00"], []];
var atLeastHours="2:00";

nextBooking(new Date(), daysAndHoursOpen, atLeastHours);
nextBooking(new Date("2020/11/6 15:30"), daysAndHoursOpen, "0:30");
nextBooking(new Date(), [[], ["07:00", "17:00"], [], [], [], [], []], atLeastHours);
nextBooking(new Date(), [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], atLeastHours);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```